# NDSolve with Euler method

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to solve this equation with `NDSolve[]` using the Euler method:

```
x'[t] == 0.5*x[t]-0.04*(x[t])^2
```

with initial condition and step size

```
x[0] == 1, h == 1
```

and final time `t = 10`.

I also don't know how to make a table including `x'[t]` and `x[t]` and time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Had the Euler method not been built-in, one could still use `NDSolve[]`'s [method plug-in framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html), which enables `NDSolve[]` to "know" how to use Euler's method.

Here's how to "teach" `NDSolve[]` the Euler method:

```
Euler[]["Step"[rhs_, t_, h_, y_, yp_]] := {h, h yp};
Euler[___]["DifferenceOrder"] := 1;
Euler[___]["StepMode"] := Fixed;
```

Plugging in the "new" method into `NDSolve[]` is a snap:

```
xa = x /. First @ NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0.5*x[t] - 0.04*(x[t])^2, x[0] == 1}, 
                          x, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> Euler, StartingStepSize -> 1];
```

Getting the corresponding table is easily done, thanks to the special methods for accessing the internals of an `InterpolatingFunction[]`:

```
pts = Transpose[Append[xa["Coordinates"], xa["ValuesOnGrid"]]]
   {{0., 1.}, {1., 1.46}, {2., 2.10474}, {3., 2.97991}, {4., 4.11467}, {5., 5.49478},
    {6., 7.03447}, {7., 8.57235}, {8., 9.91912}, {9., 10.9431}, {10., 11.6246}}
```

Showing the `InterpolatingFunction[]` and the points together in one plot is also easily done:

```
Plot[xa[t], {t, 0, 10}, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], Red, Point[pts]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: solution of differential equation via Euler]

If you wanted the derivatives as well in your table, it's easy to modify `pts`:

```
phs = Append[#, xa'[#[[1]]]] & /@ pts;
```

You can use these for the "phase plot" of your differential equation:

```
ParametricPlot[{xa[t], xa'[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
               Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], Red, Point[Rest /@ phs]}, 
               Frame -> True]
```

[image: phase plot]

The phase plot looks ugly here, since the step size was not very small and the interval of integration was not sampled well. Due to this, the `InterpolatingFunction[]` is unable to make a smooth-looking derivative. A smaller value of `StartingStepSize` (say, $1/20$) would have resulted in something that looks smoother:

[image: smoother phase plot]

but of course at the expense of more evaluations of the right-hand side.

Comment: +1. This is neat, I did not know about `NDSolve`'s plug-in framework, very useful.

Answer (score 17):

`NDSolve` has a slew of options that allow you to control the method.  You can find the standard reference [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html).

There, we learn how to access Euler's method using `NDSolve`:

```
Clear[x];
x = x /. First[
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0.5*x[t] - 0.04*(x[t])^2, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10},
  StartingStepSize -> 1, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}]
];
grid = Table[{t, x[t]}, {t, 0, 10, 1}]
ListLinePlot[grid]
```

[image: plot of differential equation solution]

It is also quite easy to program this from scratch, if you prefer.

Comment: No need for `"FixedStep"`; since *Mathematica* already ["knows" that the Euler method is a fixed step method](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html#175801995), one can do this instead: `NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0.5*x[t] - 0.04*(x[t])^2, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}, StartingStepSize -> 1, Method -> "ExplicitEuler"]`

Answer (score 11):

As Mark wrote "It is also quite easy to program this from scratch, if you prefer."

For a solution without `NDSolve` try..

```
MyEuler[start_, end_, initialvalue_, nrOfsteps_] :=Module[
       {a = start, b = end, j, m = nrOfsteps},
       h = (b - a)/m; (* fixed step-size *)
       T = Table[ a + (j - 1) h, {j, 1, m + 1}]; 
       Y = Table[ initialvalue, {j, 1, m + 1}];  
       For[ j = 1, j <= m, j++,
            Y[[j + 1]] = Y[[j]] + h  f[T[[j]], Y[[j]]];
           ]; 
       Transpose@{T, Y}]
```

Testing

```
f[t_, x_] = 0.5*x - 0.04*x^2;(* rhs of your ODE *) 
pts = MyEuler[0.0, 10.0, 1.0, 10]; 
ListLinePlot[pts, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: something like `myEuler[t0_, t1_, initial_, steps_] :=
 With[{h = (t1 - t0)/steps},
  FoldList[#1 + h f[#2, #1] &, initial, Range[t0 + h, t1, h]]]` could do

Comment: @belisarius Sure! But the OP wanted some `Table`. I guess by table he meant the array to store the discrete states as commonly done in most textbooks. I felt that mundane `For` will also better suit a classic textbook Euler ..

Comment: You could also go one step further and show how to exten NDSolve with your method.

Comment: @ruebenko I think J.M already has done exactly that while we were sleeping in Europe..right?

Comment: yes, I think he must have posted this a few minutes after the comment...

Comment: FWIW, I didn't see ruebenko's comment before I wrote my answer. After writing it, I didn't think to check for new comments, so...