# StartingStepSize as a table in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation

I would like to solve a list of equation with NDSolve with each equation having a different StartingStepSize. When I tried naively to use a table in the option NDSolve gave me an error. The only workaround I found is the solution given in [this thread.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/plotting-several-numerical-solutions-plus-the-analytic-solution-of-ode-in-one-pl/14459#14459)
However it would force me to rewrite a lot of my actual code. Does anyone know if it is possible to add a table in the options of NDSolve, or doing something equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Map`

```
step={0.001,0.01,.1}; (* starting stepsize *) 
Map[NDSolve[{x'[t]==-x[t],x[0]==1},x,{t,0,10},StartingStepSize->#]&,step]
```

which gives you a list of solutions for a given ode  with different stepsize!

For a list of odes    `MapThread[NDSolve[#1, StartingStepSize -> #2] &, {odes, step}]` solves your problem.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!