# Euler's method initial value problem — how should I plot the solution?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, homework

We are given the following initial value problem:

$\qquad y' = t\,e^{3\,t} -2\,y, \quad 0 \le t \le 1, \quad y(0)=0$

Use Euler`s method to approximate the solution to this initial value problem. In this case, the step size is $h=0.5$.

Plot the approximating solution $y_k$ along with the exact solution $y(t)$.

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the right forum? This one is about the Mathematica software. Perhaps this might fit better in https://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Yes, plot the calculated $y$ vs $t$ at the computed points.  Below is an example computed in *Mathematica*.  $n=20$ steps.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11924)

Comment: @J.M., Yes, your method there (at the linked question) is a nice way to go about it!

Answer (score 7):

**Euler's method to solve, plot, and compare to known solution:**

$y^\prime = te^{3t}-2y, \quad y(0)=0, \quad 0 \le t \le 1. $

```
y = 0; t = 0.0;
n = 20; h = 1/n;
f[y_, t_] := t Exp[3 t] - 2 y;
ξ = {y};
Do[(
  y = y + f[y, t] h;
  t = t + h;
  ξ = Join[ξ, {y}]
  ), n
]

p = Transpose[{Range[0, n]/n, ξ}];

Clear[y, t];
DSolve[{y'[t] == t Exp[3 t] - 2 y[t], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]

q = Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. %], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Gray];

Show[q, ListPlot[p, PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

Here is the output from `DSolve[]`:

```
{{y[t] -> 1/25 E^(-2 t) (1 - E^(5 t) + 5 E^(5 t) t)}}
```

Or in plain English, the solution is:

$y(t) = \frac{1}{25} (e^{-2 t} - e^{3t}+5t e^{3t})$

Here is the plot of the computed points along with the known solution (computed with `DSolve[]` above).

[image]

With $h=0.5$, Euler's method does not do so well:

[image]

Again, for $h=1/20$, we can compute `y[t]` at each approximation point and store it in the list $\eta$:

```
m = DSolve[{y'[t] == t Exp[3 t] - 2 y[t], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t];
\[Eta] = y[t] /. m /. t -> Range[0.0, n]/n;
```

Then we can tabulated $t, \xi, \eta$ (The list $\xi$ contains the Euler approximations).

```
TableForm[Transpose@Join[Transpose@N@p, \[Eta]]]
```

$\begin{array}{lll}
0.00 &0.00000000 &0.00000000\\
0.05 &0.00000000 &0.00133847\\
0.10 &0.00290459 &0.00575205\\
0.15 &0.00936342 &0.01394960\\
0.20 &0.02018940 &0.02681280\\
0.25 &0.03639170 &0.04543120\\
0.30 &0.05921500 &0.07114450\\
0.35 &0.09018750 &0.10559300\\
0.40 &0.13117800 &0.15077800\\
0.45 &0.18446200 &0.20913400\\
0.50 &0.25280800 &0.28361700\\
0.55 &0.33957000 &0.37780300\\
0.60 &0.44880500 &0.49602000\\
0.65 &0.58541300 &0.64348300\\
0.70 &0.75530400 &0.82648100\\
0.75 &0.96559000 &1.05258000\\
0.80 &1.22482000 &1.33086000\\
0.85 &1.54327000 &1.67223000\\
0.90 &1.93324000 &2.08977000\\
0.95 &2.40951000 &2.59915000\\
1.00 &2.98972000 &3.21910000\\
\end{array}$

We can also plot the error $ = \eta - \xi$:

```
ListPlot[Transpose@{Range[0, n]/n, Flatten@\[Eta] - \[Xi]}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {t, "Error=y[t]-Euler Approx."}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
forwardEuler[{t_, y_}] := {t + h, y + h f[t, y]} // N

f[t_, y_] = t*Exp[3 t] - 2 y;
h = 0.5;
steps = Floor[(1 - 0)/h];  (*0 <= t <=1 *)
ics = {0, 0};
```

With h=0.5 you get only 3 points,

```
NestList[forwardEuler, ics, steps]
{{0, 0}, {0.5, 0.}, {1., 1.12042}}
```

You have to choose more steps!

```
h = 0.05;
steps = Floor[(1 - 0)/h]; 
euler = NestList[forwardEuler, ics, steps];
ListLinePlot[euler, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Looking at your solution, I realized that I updated $t_{n+1} = t_n +h$ too early.  I've made the correction in my answer.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to compress the code and I have

```
forwardEuler[t0_, y0_, tend_, h_, func_] := 
Module[{steps = Floor[(tend - t0)/h], ics = {t0, y0}},NestList[{#[[1]] + 
h, #[[2]] + h *func /. {t -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]]}} &, ics, steps]]
```

which yields the same answer here:

```
ListLinePlot[forwardEuler[0, 0, 1, 0.05, t E^(3 t) - 2 y]]
```

[image]